Magick.Native-Q16-arm64.dll not found error in MAUI Android App
Background
I am developing a MAUI app for Android and iOS where I need to convert a HEIF (.heic) image to PNG. I have tried using several libraries for this purpose but haven't found any that support Android.
Problem
Using the package 'Magick.Net-Q16-arm64' with the following code:
var image = new MagickImage(photoData);

Where photoData is a byte array containing the image, an exception is thrown: System.DllNotFoundException: 'Magick.Native-Q16-arm64.dll'
Any suggestions?
Thank you for your time!

I dont think Magick is build for iOS and Android. I ran into the same problem when i tried to reduce the quality of my image. On Windows it all runs fine, but not on smartphones.
Underneath the link to someone else who also had this problem.
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13241
You could maybe use SkiaSharp?
using SkiaSharp;

public byte[] ConvertHeifToPng(byte[] heifData)
{
    using (SKBitmap bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(heifData))
    {
        if (bitmap == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid HEIF data");
        }

        using (SKImage image = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap))
        using (SKData pngData = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100))
        {
            return pngData.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

